# HIVE JOIN doesn't work

Tags: hive, hbase

JobTracker and TaskTracker are running and som simple queries are working !
It' metastore is `mysql` and integrated with hbase-0.94.16 .
MY tables are external

My join query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2  ON (t1.key = t2.key);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM t1 x JOIN t2 y ON (x.key = y.key)
```

or

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 JOIN t2  ON (t1.key = t2.key);
```

Non of them doesn't work and all of them return this Exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Big Table Alias is null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.MapJoinProcessor.genMapJoinLocalWork(MapJoinProcessor.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.MapJoinProcessor.genMapJoinOpAndLocalWork(MapJoinProcessor.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.convertTaskToMapJoinTask(CommonJoinResolver.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.processCurrentTask(CommonJoinResolver.java:552)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.dispatch(CommonJoinResolver.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.dispatch(TaskGraphWalker.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.walk(TaskGraphWalker.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.startWalking(TaskGraphWalker.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver.resolve(CommonJoinResolver.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.PhysicalOptimizer.optimize(PhysicalOptimizer.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genMapRedTasks(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Generate New MapJoin Opertor Exeception Big Table Alias is null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.MapJoinProcessor.genMapJoinOpAndLocalWork(MapJoinProcessor.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.convertTaskToMapJoinTask(CommonJoinResolver.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.processCurrentTask(CommonJoinResolver.java:552)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver$CommonJoinTaskDispatcher.dispatch(CommonJoinResolver.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.dispatch(TaskGraphWalker.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.walk(TaskGraphWalker.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.TaskGraphWalker.startWalking(TaskGraphWalker.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.CommonJoinResolver.resolve(CommonJoinResolver.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.physical.PhysicalOptimizer.optimize(PhysicalOptimizer.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genMapRedTasks(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8741)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
FAILED: SemanticException Generate Map Join Task Error: Generate New MapJoin Opertor Exeception Big Table Alias is null
```

Comment: Can you try when they are not null ?

Comment: Yes of course ! Both of them  have data.
so ,Your idea?

Comment: Syntax is proper, i am out of ideas.

Comment: Can you tell me the Hive version which you are using ?
Seems like hive-0.11 ?

Comment: yeah!exactly!
0.11.0.
would you mind tell more about it?Should be upgrade?

Comment: @Mark it might be worthwhile to look at this issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6552

Comment: Solved !!!!

Read the answer !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disable automatic map joins

```
Set hive.auto.convert.join=false
```